# Restriction of endomorphism on its image

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Berkeley problems

> Problem 7.4.7 Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and let $f:V\rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation. Let $W$ denote the image of $f$. Prove that the restriction of $f$ to $W$, considered as an endomorphism of $W$, has the same trace as $f:V\rightarrow V$.

Let $v$ be eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda \neq 0$. Since $\lambda v\in W$, $v=\frac{1}{\lambda}(\lambda v)\in W$. So the restriction has the same nonzero eigenvalues. How to prove their algebraic multiplicity is also the same?

Please give a hint. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go for a direct approach:

Choose a basis $\{w_1, \dots ,w_k\}$ of $\text{im}(f)$ and extend this to a basis $\beta=\{w_1, \dots, w_k,v_{k+1}, \dots ,v_n\}$ of $V$. Write $A$ for the matrix of $f$ w.r.t. the basis $\beta$. Clearly $A$ is of the form
$$\begin{pmatrix}*&*&\dots &*&\bullet&\dots &\bullet\\*&*&\dots &*&\bullet&\dots &\bullet\\ \vdots&\vdots& & \vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\*&*&\dots &*&\bullet&\dots &\bullet\\0&0&\dots &0&0&\dots&0\\\vdots&\vdots& & \vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\0&0&\dots &0&0&\dots&0
\end{pmatrix}$$
The result follows by examining this shape.